# HTML Gui designer + code generator

Tags: html

Can anyone suggest a good ui designer for html just like there exist glade , qt designer etc ??

I have searched on the net but have'nt found anything useful .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link should help:

[Best HTML Editors](http://webdesign.about.com/od/windowshtmleditors/tp/best_windows_html_editors.htm)

Here is a complete list:

[List of HTML Editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_editors)

I use mainly visual studio 2010 for my html but I guess if your more geared towards ui you can aim for Expression Web or Adobe Dreamweaver. HTH

**I Recommend** you use Visual Studio or Expression Web because they contain a toolbox with drag and drop html and asp.net controls that generate html code. Really you could possibly do everything in design view without ever having to write html code.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but doesn't HTML editor mean that they help in providing features to write HTML code ? I was looking for a type of designer wherein drag and drop features exist and html code gets generated automatically ....

Comment: @user506710 Yeah most of the ones I put have that capability. Expresssion Web, Dreamweaver, Visual Studio all support code intellisense and drag and drop.

Comment: But Expression Web on their main site says that it is not a WYSWYG and requires knowledge of html ?? Should I use it??

Comment: @user506710 When making a website it is almost certain that you will eventually have to work with the html code directly. The nice things about these programs is the controls I was talking about. And when if necessary they both provide intellisense which makes it extremely easy to work with html. Yes I suggest you use it because these are the best in the market in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

[aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) is probably what you want, NVU, Dreamweaver, also.